# Remind me to give it to you

Tags: traducción

Which, if either, of these are correct for "Remind me to give it to you".

Recuérdeme dártelo.

Recuérdeme que te lo dé.

Answer (score 10):

Both are right, just changing *Recuérdeme* por *Recuérdame*. The first one is third person, or *usted*, but in that case should be *dárselo* or *que se lo dé*.

*Tildes* are also missing ;)

Recuérdame dártelo.
Recuérdame que te lo dé.

If I have to say which one is more common, maybe I would say the second one.

Comment: Yes, when using "recuérdame" the correct way is whichever form follows with "que". That first way isn't technically incorrect, but it sounds weird to a native speaker.

Answer (score 1):

Only the second one ("Recuérdame que te lo dé") is a correct translation for "Remind me to give it to you".

In Spanish, as in other languages like French, infinitives are used this way only if the subjects for both of the verbs are the same. Here, the one who reminds is not the one who gives, so an infinitive is not adequate.

Note that I changed also the person to accord, like machlas said.